# How to group messages by username?

Tags: scala

A message class:

```
case class Message(username:String, content:String)
```

A message list:

```
val list = List(
    Message("aaa", "111"), 
    Message("aaa","222"), 
    Message("bbb","333"),
    Message("aaa", "444"),
    Message("aaa", "555"))
```

How to group the messages by name and get the following result:

```
List( "aaa"-> List(Message("aaa","111"), Message("aaa","222")), 
      "bbb" -> List(Message("bbb","333")),
      "aaa" -> List(Message("aaa","444"), Message("aaa", "555")) )
```

That means, if a user post several messages, then group them together, until another user posted. The order should be kept.

Comment: Did you bother looking into the API? Like look at `List` and there's a message `groupBy`...

Comment: @ziggystar, `groupBy` can't be used here, since it will group ALL the messages of user "aaa" together. This is not what I want.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the last sentence.

Comment: This is a recurring question, but everyone asks it in a different manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't think of an easy way to do this with the provided `Seq` methods, but you can write your own pretty concisely with a fold:

```
def contGroupBy[A, B](s: List[A])(p: A => B) = (List.empty[(B, List[A])] /: s) {
  case (((k, xs) :: rest), y) if k == p(y) => (k, y :: xs) :: rest
  case (acc, y) => (p(y), y :: Nil) :: acc
}.reverse.map { case (k, xs) => (k, xs.reverse) }
```

Now `contGroupBy(list)(_.username)` gives you what you want.

Comment: Thanks, but I have to say, the code is so complicated that I can't even understand ...

Comment: @Freewind: Cheers for cleaning up my code a bit—I was apparently typing faster than I was thinking.

Answer (score 3):

I tried to create such a code which works not only with Lists and can be written in operator notation. I came up with this:

```
object Grouper {
  import collection.generic.CanBuildFrom

  class GroupingCollection[A, C, CC[C]](ca: C)(implicit c2i: C => Iterable[A]) {
    def groupBySep[B](f: A => B)(implicit
        cbf: CanBuildFrom[C,(B, C),CC[(B,C)]],
        cbfi: CanBuildFrom[C,A,C]
    ): CC[(B, C)] =
      if (ca.isEmpty) cbf().result
      else {
        val iter = c2i(ca).iterator
        val outer = cbf()
        val inner = cbfi()
        val head = iter.next()
        var olda = f(head)

        inner += head
        for (a <- iter) {
          val fa = f(a)
          if (olda != fa) {
            outer += olda -> inner.result
            inner.clear()
          }
          inner += a
          olda = fa
        }
        outer += olda -> inner.result
        outer.result
      }    
  }
  implicit def GroupingCollection[A, C[A]](ca: C[A])(
      implicit c2i: C[A] => Iterable[A]
  ): GroupingCollection[A, C[A], C] =
    new GroupingCollection[A, C[A],C](ca)(c2i)
}
```

Can be used (with Lists, Seqs, Arrays, ...) as:

```
list groupBySep (_.username)
```

Comment: WOW

+1 for the nice generic solution

+1 for the CanBuildFrom use example


-1 for unreadable names

-1 for whole C++-style code

+1 for really generic solution

-------------------------
+1

Comment: @Odomontois: Yes, I got it! ;) The code is ugly, I know. But on the other side it is probably the most efficient one we can get when working with CanBuildFrom.

Answer (score 2):

```
def group(lst: List[Message], out: List[(String, List[Message])] = Nil)
                                 : List[(String, List[Message])] = lst match {
  case Nil => out.reverse
  case Message(u, c) :: xs => 
    val (same, rest) = lst span (_.username == u)
    group(rest, (u -> same) :: out)
}
```

Tail recursive version. Usage is simply `group(list)`.

Comment: Hi Luigi, would you mind explaining your choice of default argument for out, would Nil or even List() work or is there a compromise in making these more concise choices?

Comment: Thanks Don, `Nil` is a much better way of putting it! Updated.

Answer (score 1):

```
(List[Tuple2[String,List[Message]]]() /: list) {
  case (head :: tail, msg) if msg.username == head._1 =>
    (msg.username -> (msg :: head._2)) :: tail
  case (xs, msg) =>
    (msg.username -> List(msg)) :: xs
} map { t => t._1 -> t._2.reverse } reverse
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another method using pattern matching and tail recursion.  Probably not as efficient as those above though due to the use of both takeWhile and dropWhile.

```
def groupBy(msgs: List[Message]): List[(String,List[Message])] = msgs match {     
    case Nil => List()
    case head :: tail => (head.username -> 
        (head :: tail.takeWhile(m => m.username == head.username))) +:  
         groupBy(tail.dropWhile(m => m.username == head.username))
}
```